# How can I enchant an item with an enchantment table?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm running around with mobs chasing and I walk up to my enchantment table and realize I don't know how to enchant.

Comment: This answer is really low quality. It shows almost no research effort. A simple google search would have answered this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting#Enchantment_Table) :

> Enchanting through an Enchantment Table requires a specific number of Experience Levels and Lapis Lazuli in order to be executed. Once the required tool/armor is placed, the player may select from a choice of 3 enchantments, each requiring different amount of levels and Lapis Lazuli. Once the player selects one, the item will be enchanted.

So, kill mobs and mine for XP, find Lapis Lazuli, and enchant you items.

Comment: @user143995 Welcome on Arqade. Feel free to mark the question as 'answered' if my answer was useful ;)